# Please merge [gps] and [internal-gps]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Can you please merge these tags. I believe they are redundant.

- [internal-gps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-gps)
- [gps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good point, I could see the point with an "External GPS" tag, but I think at this point we can safely assume that any question about GPS refers to the internal GPS unless otherwise specified.

Have had a look through the only three questions that were tagged "internal gps" and couldn't see anything on them that required the distinction. Have removed the "internal gps" tag from them all.